# Index out of bounds while processing CSV

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I'm trying to put all my text formatted CSVs in a list or array. The exception goes:

> Index was outside the bound of the array.

Its something I just missed maybe...

```
static void Main()
{
    /// 
    /// CSV Headers: Code PostDate, T, Description, RecTyp, PropAccountNmbr, Amount
    ///
    string[] CSVs = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\csv\");

    try
    {
        foreach (string Files in CSVs)
        {
            string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(Files);
            var query = File.ReadAllLines(Files)
               .Skip(1)
               .Select(x => x.Split(','))
               .Select(x => new
               {
                   Code = x[0],
                   PostDate = x[1],
                   T = int.Parse(x[2]),
                   Description = x[3],
                   RecTyp = x[4],
                   PropAccountNmbr = x[5],
                   Amount = float.Parse(x[6])
               });

            foreach (var s in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6}", 
                    s.Code, s.PostDate, s.T, s.Description, s.RecTyp, s.PropAccountNmbr, s.Amount);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Here is a sample of the CSV, problem is this CSV is a text document (.txt) that has a CSV format:

```
Code PostDate   T Description                    RecTyp PropAccountNmbr                    Amount
bk  ,2015-03-01,2,Bankard                       ,none  ,000210709109            ,        32284.50
bpi ,2015-03-01,2,BPI Classic                   ,none  ,000210709107            ,         3415.18
bpi ,2015-03-01,2,BPI Classic                   ,none  ,000210709107            ,        19780.00
```

Comment: are u sure all lines have 7 itens?

Comment: does your csv have 7 fields in all lines?

Comment: Can you show us *where* in the code the exception is thrown? On which line of code? Also, can you show us the data it chokes on?

Comment: Can you add a file sample.

Comment: @George & Marc B: Yes, here is a sample from my CSV Text: Code PostDate   T Description                    RecTyp PropAccountNmbr                    Amount

bk  ,2015-03-01,2,Bankard                       ,none  ,000210709109            ,        32284.50

bpi ,2015-03-01,2,BPI Classic                   ,none  ,000210709107            ,         3415.18

Comment: I just checked the CSV that was given to me and the headers are tabbed (updated the question). Would that be the cause of it?

Comment: @BinaryWorrier Yeah its on the catch below. I updated the description with the included sample of the CSV text.

Comment: Your code seems to be good to me after seeing your csv example. Is the file content you pasted the one that is giving you troubles?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi Exactly, I think I should change the title to how can I read CSV with a tabbed header and comma separated values.

Comment: Why don't you debug every step to see where this gets wrong? Since you're skipping the header it's not relevant if it's tabbed or not.

Comment: This code and the sample csv run fine for me, do you have other files in the directory that could be bad since this will get all the files and run them?

Comment: @Marko There are multiple csv text files in the directory that I intend to loop through.

Comment: I updated the description again. The CSV files given to me are .txt files and not .csv files. I was able to display the first line of data but unfortunately I could not loop through the next line and so on. It runs to the index exception afterwards. Not sure if the .txt file type is the cause. Any suggestions anyone?

Comment: @JoshuaMasangcay, i recommend you to do a foreach, instead a compelte linq query, this way you can debug and see exactly what line is giving you the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper parser to process CSV.

This one is pretty well-accepted: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

Barebones example:

```
static void Main()
{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\logs", "*.csv");

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(file, Encoding.UTF8), true))
        {
            var rows = csv.Select(row => String.Join(" ", row));
            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(row);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Recommended reading on the side: [Stop Rolling Your Own CSV Parser!](http://www.secretgeek.net/csv_trouble)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who commented: I simplified the code to just put all the values in an array as they are written in console. I also removed .Select lambda with creating new object so I could get rid of the out of bounding array exception.